# Imagecreatefromjpeg returns false even if image is exists

Tags: php, php-gd

This code returns false:

```
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("photos/profiles/original/4cdf149b63d0ca0158f68357d8da371c_y.jpg");
    var_dump($image);
    exit;
```

But this code:

```
    $image = getimagesize("photos/profiles/original/4cdf149b63d0ca0158f68357d8da371c_y.jpg");
    var_dump($image);
    exit;
```

Returns this:

```
array(7) { [0]=> int(2576) [1]=> int(1932) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> string(26) "width="2576" height="1932"" ["bits"]=> int(8) ["channels"]=> int(3) ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }
```

Also i can see the photo from any web browsers or something etc. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: `gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `gd.jpeg_ignore_warning` and using the `@` to suppress the error mentioned in the comment appears to work but for some inexplicable reason rotates the image by 90 degrees ~ perhaps the image was taken on a mobile?

```
<?php


    ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);

    $src='c:/temp2/4cdf149b63d0ca0158f68357d8da371c_y.jpg';
    $img=@imagecreatefromjpeg( $src );


    header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
    imagejpeg( $img );
    imagedestroy( $img );
?>
```

Comment: Yep, image was taken on a mobile. Is it safe to use this ini set?

Comment: yes, should be OK to use that ~ only affects the setting temporarily for the duration of the script

Comment: I have not yet read this but it might help fix the rotation issue. https://medium.com/thetiltblog/fixing-rotated-mobile-image-uploads-in-php-803bb96a852c

Answer (score 0):

Check error log or do

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

to get more information, GD might use E_NOTICE error level to pass more information on the issue